# Google Analytics banner?

Tags: google, traffic, google-analytics

I use Google Analytics on my site...

But, I would like to display some traffic info to the users, like geo localization or just a hit-counter on the main page of my site.

Does Google offer something like this?

Comment: Google Analytics has an API, but AFAIK the user needs to have an authorized login and password to see data from the stats. The easiest way to do this is to use another web service as a counter. Under a marketing/usability perspective counters are considered unnecessary and a distraction to users. Unless you have a huge audience and your audience values the popularity of your site.

Comment: @Osvaldo: Surely, it needs authorisation, to see the complete statistics. But I just need to put a small "banner" with location of visitors of my little site(like geovisitors http://geo.digitalpoint.com/a.png), or hitcounter - all i need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can through the [Analytics API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/). For an example of a site that uses the API to openly display data from Analytics including Page Views, Time on Site, Direct Referral, Search Referrals, and more [see this SEOmoz post](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/raising-the-bar-on-data-sharing-introducing-open-analytics), and then click "Post Analytics" at the bottom of this or any other blog post on that site.

However, note that it sounds like the data can be slow to retrieve, and there may be other limitations, so you may not want to use it in a traditional 'hit counter' fashion. (I would [search StackOverflow for the many existing topics](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hit%20counter) on simpler hit counter methods.)